# How to handle a generated big form in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to generate a big form based on what I get from the server.
sometimes I generate 32 elements sometimes 57 or 4 I don't know. 
I try to create a component for each type of element like select, text, number, textarea and so on.
each component passes the value to the parent component and setState the value to the parent.

imagine I have 20 inputs and custom select-option elements.
when I type something in one of the inputs characters show up after 2seconeds and there is a huge lag in my component.
I know because of the setState method my hole component (I mean my parent component or my single source of truth) re-renders and causes the problem.

in fact, I don't know other ways.
I try to use a "this.VARIABLE" and instead of setState, I update the "this.VARIABLE" and problem solved. but I need my state.

any help or solution?

my code (parent Component, source of truth ):

```js
// ---> find my component based on the type that I get from server
findComponent ( item , index) {

        if ( item.type === 'text' || item.type === 'number') {
            return (<Text data={item} getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else if ( item.type === 'longtext') {
            return (<Textarea data={item} getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else if ( item.type === 'select' ) {
            return (<SelectOption data={item} getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else if ( item.type === 'autocomplete') {
            return (<AutoTag data={item} url={URL1} getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else if ( item.type === 'checkbox_comment' ) {
            return (<CheckboxComment data={item} getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else if ( item.type === 'multiselect' ) {
            return (<Multiselect data={item}  getUpdated={this.fetchingComponentData} />);

        } else {
            return (<p>THERE IS NO TYPE OF => {item.type}</p>);
        }
    }


// ----> if i setState here ==> big lag
fetchingComponentData(OBJ) {

        let index = null;
        // let Answer = [...this.state.Answer];

            index = Helper.find_item(this.Answer , OBJ , 'unique_key');

            if ( index === -1 ) {
                this.Answer.push(OBJ);
            } else {
                this.Answer[index].value = OBJ.value;
            }
    }


// ----> in my render method

render () {
return (
                <React.Fragment>
    
                    <div className="row Technical section" data-info="Technical">
                        <div className="col-6">
                            
                            {data.map( (item,index) => {
                                return (
                                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                            
                                        <div className="rowi">
                                            {item.attributes.map( (item, index)=> {
                                                return <React.Fragment key={index}>{this.findComponent(item, index)}</React.Fragment>;
                                            })}
                                        </div>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-6"></div>
                    </div>
    
                </React.Fragment>
            );
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a codesandbox or post your code?

Comment: no, but I put some part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make an object out of your components and pass it to setState at once?

```
const nextState = componentList.map(component => {
    return {[component]: value};
});

this.setState({...nextState});
```

**Edit:** Okay i got another part you could do better.

You should build an array with you components in `componentWillMount` function instead of fetching all the data inside the render. Like you said, it's updating everytime any state changes, and all the components are also updating with the parent.

This is to be made in addition with what I suggested before, but it is of far more importance because of the impact on the ressource.

Comment: You are doing it component by component inside `fetchingComponentData(OBJ)`, which is not what I suggest

Comment: I am sorry I don't get u.
each component return a value and unique_key  to parent component by "getUpdated" and I save the value based on unique_key inside of the fetchingComponentData if I store the uniqe_key and value into the "this.Answer" 
there would be no LAG but if I just use setState then I see LAG. that's all.

Comment: I updated my answer. Indeed it's lagging when you call setState, because you call it in every iteration in the item.attributes array, making the parent refresh again and again